# Difference in reactivity of sodium ethoxide and NaOH in ethanol

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, elimination, reagents

What is the difference in the reaction that proceeds when we use the reagent $\ce{C2H5O- Na+}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ in $\ce{C2H5OH}$ in with, say ethyl chloride. Is the latter considered to be "alcoholic NaOH"?

$$\ce{CH3-CH2-Cl}$$

As per my understanding, $\ce{OH-}$ in $\ce{C2H5OH}$ exist in an equilibrium with $\ce{C2H5O-}$ and $\ce{H2O}$, with the formation being favoured due to a basic medium provided by $\ce{NaOH}$
$$\ce{C_2H_5OH + OH- <=> C_2H_5O- + H2O}$$
$$\ce{C_2H_5O- + CH_3-CH_2-Cl -> C_2H_5OC_2H_5}$$
$$\ce{C_2H_5O- + CH_3-CH_2-Cl -> CH_2=CH_2}$$
Given that the substrate is a primary chloride, nucleophilic substitution by $\ce{C2H5O-}$ seems to be the most favourable pathway, as compared to E2-elimination. (Williamson synthesis)

However, I have seen in multiple books that both alkenes/ethers are given as products in different instances, with the reagents I mentioned being used interchangeably. What is the difference between them and what is the major product formed?

Comment: With sodium ethoxide, there are no traces of water.

Comment: @Karsten what are the implications of that?

Comment: Depends on the specifics of the reaction.

Comment: @Karsten Could you give some examples of the variables that would decide the major product in the two cases?

Comment: Temperature, solvent, nucleophilicity/basicity of reagents, steric hindrance of the base are some examples.

Comment: What about this particular example?considering ethyl chloride

Comment: If the nucleophile/base is not a variable, you still can choose different temperature and solvent.

Answer (score 2):

NaOH dissolved in ethanol gives a mix of hydroxide and ethoxide depending on how much water is present. To run a reaction with a pure alkoxide the procedure is to dry the alcohol and to generate the alkoxide by careful reaction of the alcohol with the appropriate metal preferably under an N2 atmosphere. Alkoxide solutions can be purchased.

The balance of E2-SN2, E1-SN1 can be complicated and is best investigated on an individual basis. If interested in the Williamson synthesis check here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williamson_ether_synthesis

Comment: And how does that affect their reactivity towards ethyl chloride?